# Why is composer not adding a package?

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm trying to add a new composer dependency to my project, but it doesn't work. There's no error or anything - it just silently does nothing:

```
[vagrant@localhost project]$ composer require bshaffer/oauth2-server-bundle
Using version ^0.4.0 for bshaffer/oauth2-server-bundle
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

[vagrant@localhost project]$ composer update --verbose
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

That's it. That's all the output. What is going on? Why isn't composer downloading and installing the package?

Additional info:

- The machine has PHP 5.6 installed.
- The project has Symfony 2.8 installed and a bunch of other libraries.
- There is a `composer.lock` file, but no matter what I do, the `bshaffer/oauth2-server-bundle` doesn't get added to it. I'm afraid to completely delete and recreate the file.
- Deleting `vendor/` and other auto-generate files, and then running `composer install` results in all the libraries being reinstalled **except** `bshaffer/oauth2-server-bundle`.

Comment: I suspect that it comes from `composer` version installed. What does `composer --version` shows you ? You can see a list of versions there https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: You may be running out of memory maybe? I have seen card where composer takes A LOT of memory to run.

Comment: @AlvaroFlañoLarrondo I've had that too, many times, but normally that produces a clear exception message at the end.

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant Latest. As one of the things I tried I updated composer itself to the latest version. No change.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a memory issue after all. The project is in a virtual machine with 2GB of RAM allocated. Since there is basically nothing else there, that's enough for smooth daily operation. Except composer, apparently. I increased the amount of available RAM to the VM, and here are the results:

- At 2GB - terminates silently, no error messages or anything
- At 4GB - terminates with an error message that there's not enough memory to `fork`.
- At 8GB - Works as expected, woohoo!

Seriously, 8GB? Bloatware these days! When I grew up...

Answer (score -1):

The composer is running in the background. To see the output simply use the verbose mode, so modify your commaand to

```
composer require bshaffer/oauth2-server-bundle  -vvv
```

Also you can try deleting the lock file that is composer-lock.json before re running the command

Comment: I added the `-vvv` flag and it showed me LOTS more of output... but that too ends rather abruptly. The last line is `Reading /home/vagrant/.cache/composer/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/provider-bshaffer$oauth2-server-httpfoundation-bridge.json from cache`. There's a hundred lines like that before it, each for a different package. I'm starting to suspect that it's crashing, but there is no error message...

Comment: You can try deleting the composer-lock.json as this file is generated automatically by composer when it installs the dependencies and see if this installs the bshaffer package, also delete the vendor folder.

Answer (score -1):

Please **delete** the file **composer-lock.json** and then try running **composer install**.

Comment: Trying now. Although I'm a bit uneasy about this since it was checked in git and we've had problems with updating in the past (as in, a newer version of a package not working). Ideally I'd like to just add this one package without touching the rest.